# Branch Cut Intersection

Tags: complex-analysis

**NB Mods: I am asking about something entirely different about this question than I asked before**

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing that the solution to this question is not very detailed. Even though I have parameterised; when $k+1=0$ I am effectively working out the $\displaystyle \int_\gamma  \frac{1}{z} dz$

so do I not have to consider the fact that the curve $e^{i\theta}: \space \theta \in[0,2\pi]$ intersects the branch cut of Log at
$[-\infty,0]$?

Answer (score 1):

No, just compute it directly:

If $k + 1 = 0$, then $e^{ik\theta}e^{i\theta} = 1$ and the integral to compute is

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} i \,d\theta.
$$